# Docker instance port Management

Tags: node.js, docker

I have different docker instances and I need to start node.js processes in each of these instances. For this to happen, is it needed that each of them start on different port numbers? How does the container manage that and is there a docker management system for it?  I want the client to know which port has the instance initiated the node.js process. How can this be automated?

Answer (score 0):

this problem is called "orchestration".  I kind of think Docker is a bit overblown because it actually doesn't solve this problem.

Kubernetes is an open source tool.  Tutum is an online service.  Docker has started a [tool](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) but it's not done.

Honestly, it's a bit of a cluster-show at the moment.  If you're not hosting 20+ instances, I'd recommend building bash scripts.

Currently, I use a bespoke solution made from DigitalOcean, [Dokku](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/), and bash scripting.  This gives me the flexibility of a self-hosted Heroku like environment that is very dev friendly.

Dokku let's you deploy docker apps using a 'git push'.  It reads files in your repo to build the image.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to start the applications inside docker on different ports. You can map any port (for example, port 80) inside the docker container to any port on your host machine.

There is no rule about how to use this to your benefit.

If your clients all have ids say in the 1-10000 range, you can map the docker container's port 80 to "client_id + 20000".

Comment: I am his team mate. We want to create docker instances on run time.  How do I ensure if I am starting lets  say a docker instance exposed on port X - how do i make sure X is not being used - clients will be making TCP connections to this machine. What if X was reserved for docker but client connected using port 'X'.

Comment: How would a client connect to the machine on that port if there is nothing listening on that port?